# How can I use parent_id in Django?

Tags: python, django

In my model:

```
class HomePageFirstModule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # 是否启用


class HomePageSecondModule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # 是否启用
    home_page_first_module = models.ForeignKey(to=HomePageFirstModule) # 所属的第一级模块


class HomePageThridModule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # 是否启用
    home_page_second_module = models.ForeignKey(to=HomePageSecondModule)  # 所属的第二级模块
```

Then I use filter method to query out the data:

```
def get_homepage_module_list():
    """
    获取到可以使用的模块信息
    :return:
    """

    data_query_list = models.HomePageThridModule.objects.filter(
        home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module="1"
    ).values('id', 'name', 'is_active', 'home_page_second_module__name',
             'home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name',
             'home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__is_active',
             'home_page_second_module__is_active'
             )

    data_list_del = []
    data_list = list(data_query_list)
    for item in data_list:
        if (item['is_active'] == False) or (
                    item['home_page_second_module__is_active'] == False
        ) or (
                item['home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__is_active'] == False
        ):
            data_list_del.append(item)

    for item_del in data_list_del:
        data_list.remove(item_del)

    return data_list
```

========================

---

How can I convert this list data :

```
[
    {
        "home_page_second_module__name": "云主机",
        "home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name": "产品",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "云主机子1"
    },
    {
        "home_page_second_module__name": "云主机",
        "home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name": "产品",
        "id": 4,
        "name": "云主机子4"
    },
    {
        "home_page_second_module__name": "云硬盘",
        "home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name": "产品",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "云硬盘子2"
    },
    {

        "home_page_second_module__name": "云硬盘",
        "home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name": "产品",
        "id": 3,
        "name": "云硬盘子3"
    }
]
```

to this:

```
[
    {"name":"产品",
     "data":[
        {"name":"云主机",
         "data":[{"name":"云主机子1",
                  "data":{"id":1}},
                 {"name":"云主机子2",
                  "data":{"id":2}}]},
        {"name":"云硬盘",
         "data":[{"name":"云硬盘子1",
                  "data":{"id":3}},
                 {"name":"云硬盘子2",
                  "data":{"id":4}}]}
     ]
    }
]
```

There should has a arithmetic method to do this, but I tried, do not get that.

I only think of this below little things:

```
home_page_second_module__name_list = []
home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name_list = []
id_list = []
name_list = []

for home_page_second_module__name,home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name,id,name  in ori_list:
    if not (home_page_second_module__name_list.__contains__(home_page_second_module__name)):
        home_page_second_module__name_list.append(home_page_second_module__name)
    if not (home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name_list.__contains__(home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name_list)):
        home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name_list.append(home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name)
```

But now I think this is very difficult to do that, and I think mine is wrong way to do that.

Is there a convenient way to realize it?

---

**EDIT**

The `产品`, `云主机`, `云硬盘` may can be deed as parent id.

Comment: In java maybe can use `parentid` to realize, but in python I don't know how to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

*Outdated code, as the original question just asked how to transform a list of dicts into another list of dicts with different outcome*

I bet this can optimized a lot but... assuming your dict is named old, I think this might do it:

```
new = {'name': i['home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name'] for i in old if not i['home_page_second_module__home_page_first_module__name'] in old}
new['data'] = [['name': i['home_page_second_module__name'], 'data':[{'name': i['home_page_second_module__name'], 'data': {'id': i['id']}}]] for i in old]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-rest-framework, and use related serializers. [relations serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)